# Compare array elements in two different structured array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 different structured arrays and i need to find matched and mismatched elements and output result in table. I've found matched elements, but im having troubles with finding mismatched ones. First array always have more elements than second one. Heres some parts of 2 arrays:

```
$sheetData = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01008039918
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01008302495
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01008603263
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01008690496
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01008985481
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40020755400
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40032435000
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40231570009
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40309872408
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40311901009
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40353576000
    )


$found = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40594677009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40594677400
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40595693002
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40595693400
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 01008302495
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 01008309812
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40690651009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40690651404
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40625090009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40625090400
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40708294009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40708294400
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40499752009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40499752404
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40604404009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40604404400
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40425581009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40425581404
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 40440897009
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 40440897408
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO] => 01008603263
        [EXT_ACCOUNT_ID] => 01008610730
    )
```

More details about the desired output, if element from first array is found in INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO, corresponding EXT_ACCOUNT_ID should be displayed in table, then after all found matched elements, place one empty row, then if element from first array is not found in INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO, just copy value to same table row.

Ive found matched values, but i cant figure out how to find mismatched elements after one empty row, im getting some duplicate entries and some copies from matched entries, this is my code:

```
echo"<table class=\"table style=\"max-width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;\">
<thead>
     <tr>                                
             <th>INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO</th>                               
             <th>EXT_ACCOUNT_ID</th>
         </tr>  
</thead>        
<tbody>";                       
foreach ($sheetData as $sheet_key => $sheet_data) { 
    foreach ($found as $found_key => $found_val) {                              
       if ($sheet_data[0] == $found_val['INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO']) {  
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$sheet_data[0]."</td>";                                      
                echo "<td>".$found_val['EXT_ACCOUNT_ID']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }                                                                   
     }
 }  

echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>"."&nbsp;"."</td>";
   echo "<td>"."&nbsp;"."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($sheetData as $sheet_key => $sheet_data) { 
   foreach ($found as $found_key => $found_val) {                               
       if ($sheet_data[0] != $found_val['INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO'] && $found_val['EXT_ACCOUNT_ID'] == $found_val['INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO']) {    
           echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$sheet_data[0]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$sheet_data[0]."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
        }                                                                           
    }
 }                  
 echo "<tbody>";
 echo "</table>";
```

Any correction of code above is welcomed. Thx.

Comment: Shouldn't this grouping be done in the mysql query?  Please show your exact, desired, rendered output for clarity.

Comment: unfortunately, i can work only with given values

Comment: What do you mean by `just copy value to same table row.`?

Comment: Just to copy that id number in next column in same row

Answer (score 0):

When looking for mismatches you could use `array_diff` or `array_diff_key` where `array_diff` will show mismatches of the values and `array_diff_key` will show the keys, something like this as an example:

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

This will give you "yellow" because it's a mismatch.

Comment: I've tried that, but that gives me only differences in array keys

Comment: @Greedy Are you sure that it wasn't `array_diff_key` you tried? `array_diff` is on the values only, `array_diff_key` is on the keys only.

Answer (score 0):

No need of too much loop.
First convert your sheet array to normal array

```
$sheet_data = [];
foreach ($sheetData as $key => $value) {
    $sheet_data[] = $value[0];
}
```

Now saperate matched and unmatched $found data:

```
$matched_elements = [];
$unmatched_elements = [];
foreach ($found as $found_key => $found_val) {
   if (in_array($found_val['INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO'],$sheet_data)) {
     $matched_elements[] = $found_val;
    }
    else {
      $unmatched_elements[] = $found_val;
    }
 }
```

Now you use  arrays for display matched and unmatched data

```
foreach ($matched_elements as $found_key => $found_val) {
    echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$found_val[INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$found_val['EXT_ACCOUNT_ID']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Unmatched elements :

```
foreach ($unmatched_elements as $found_key => $found_val) {
    echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$found_val[INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$found_val['EXT_ACCOUNT_ID']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `$found` a dictionary for performance. Here is just a demo, you need to format the output content.

```
$sheetData = array_column($sheetData,null,"INDIVIDUAL_PAYMNET_REFNO");
foreach($array as $value){
    if(isset($sheetData[$value])){
        echo $sheetData[$value]["EXT_ACCOUNT_ID"] . "<br/>";
    }else{
        $notFoundedData[] = $value;
    }
}
echo "<br/>";
foreach($notFoundedData as $value){
    echo $value . "<br/>";
}
```